# java.lang.IllegalStateException: wile adding views to inflating layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I am having a fragment, in which i am inflating an item other than frgments view, which contains a linear layout. it is inflating fine, but now the problem is, when I am referring it, and trying to add a TextView programmatically in linear layout, it thorws an error. Any help will be preferable.

**Error:** java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Fragment.java

```
    public class ShortFrag extends Fragment{
    ListView listview;
    LinearLayout row1;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.r_fragment, container, false);

        listview=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        LayoutInflater myinflater = getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup myHeader = (ViewGroup) myinflater.inflate(R.layout.helper, listview, false);

        row1= headerViewHolder.findViewById(R.id.linear);

        TextView tv = getTextView(getTextView("button_one","button"));

        //error here
        row1.addView(tv);

        return view;
    }

    private TextView getTextView(String text, String tag) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.black));
        textView.setTag(tag);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewPager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
        return textView;
    }
}
```

r_fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<Listview 
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

helper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `row1.addView(getTextView(getTextView("button_one","button")));` - With the given code, that won't compile, and therefore could never throw that Exception. What's the actual code?

Comment: replace this line
row1.addView(getTextView(getTextView("button_one","button"))); with 
row1.addView(getTextView("button_one","button"));

Comment: Mike you are right, and it solved my problem. I edited my question. But, Can you tell me the reason for this ?

Comment: Uh, not really, 'cause this won't compile either: `TextView tv = getTextView(getTextView("button_one","button"));`. You don't have a `getTextView()` method that can take a `TextView` argument. I don't know what you did to fix that particular Exception.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 //error here
 row1.removeAllViews();
 row1.addView(tv);
```